# Netbeans/Mercurial - Define multiple push/pull repositories under the "Team -> Share" menu?

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, push, dvcs

In Netbeans w/Mercurial you have a menu that lists your default push/pull repositories along with an option for "other" to manually specify a repository to push/pull:

[image: push/pull menu]

My "default push/pull" is set to our central repository, but my working repositories are pulled into a staging repository first. Needless to say, I could use more items in the "Share" menu than just "default push/pull". Is there a way to define more, so it would look something like:

```
- Share
--- Push to default
--- Push to my-other-repo-1
--- Push to my-other-repo-2
--- Push to other
--- Pull from default
--- Pull from my-other-repo-1
--- Pull from my-other-repo-2
--- Pull from other
```

Currently I just select "pull from other" but then have to manually type in the other repositories' information each time.

Answer (score 2):

I looked in the [source for the Mercurial integration with NetBeans](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/release71_base/mercurial/src/org/netbeans/modules/mercurial?style=paper) and it is not possible to extend the menu. It is simply [created](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/release71_base/mercurial/src/org/netbeans/modules/mercurial/ui/menu/ShareMenu.java?style=paper) with a single menu item for "Push Other..." and "Pull Other...".

Mercurial actually has [a mechanism](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#paths) whereby you can add shortcuts to other repositories:

```
[paths]
default = http://server/mike-transcodes-719
my-other-repo-1 = ssh://server/other-repo11
my-other-repo-2 = http://server/other-repo-2
```

With such a section in your `.hg/hgrc` file, you can now do

```
$ hg pull my-other-repo-1
```

on the command line. However, NetBeans only read the `default`, `default-push`, and `default-pull` values from the `[paths]` section in your `.hg/hgrc` file. It would have been smart to include other push/pull paths in the menu, but they're ignored.

This is as of NetBeans version 7.1, hopefully this changes in the future.